Authorize user with organization name provided by subsomain
I am trying to implement the following login flow on a Nextjs app with Auth0:
(Assume that organizations and users are already defined)

User access org1.domain.com
The app register org1 then immediatly redirect user to Auth0 Universal Login UI with organization already registered, user now only has to provide email and password
If successfully authenticated, redirect user to domain.com/org1

So far, I have implemented:

Created app/[subdomain]/page.tsx

Toggled on "Allow Organization name in Authorization API" in auth0 settings and chose Business login as well as "No prompt" login

Add these URL in Allowed callback URL:


http://localhost:3002/api/auth/callback, http://{organization_name}.localhost:3002, http://localhost:3002/* 

Add middleware to handle requests

middleware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import {getAccessToken} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";


export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  const hostHeader = req.headers.get('host');
  const orgName = hostHeader.split('.')[0];

  // If on root and there exist a subdomain (e.g abc.domain.com)
  if (pathname === '/' && orgName !== '') {

    // Redirect the user to Auth0 authorization URL with organization as a query param
    const auth0Url = new URL(`${process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL}/authorize`);
    auth0Url.searchParams.append('client_id', `${process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}`);
    auth0Url.searchParams.append('response_type', 'code');
    auth0Url.searchParams.append('redirect_uri', `http://localhost:3002/${orgName}`);
    auth0Url.searchParams.append('scope', 'openid profile email');
    auth0Url.searchParams.append('organization', `${orgName}`); // Optional: dynamically set this

    return NextResponse.redirect(auth0Url.toString());
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

When I access org1.localhost:3002, it says

The provided redirect_uri is not in the list of allowed callback URLs.

I also tried redirect uri as http://localhost:3002/api/auth/callback but it gave HTTP 400 error instead.
What did I do wrong?
Thank you.
